# Firebird - Incorrect SYSDBA password

Tags: firebird2.5

I just installed Firebird using:

```
apt-get install firebird2.5-super
```

Everything went fine and it prompted me for the SYSDBA password. I thought I entered the standard 'masterkey' but must have mis-typed because I can't connect or use GSEC/etc.

So I autoremoved Firebird and tried to install again. It installed but did not ask me for the SYSDBA password again. It would seem that the autoremove does not remove the file which contains the SYSDBA password.

So I'm stuck. Can anyone help? Cheers. Eric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to set new password:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-super`



Or this to test current password:

`sudo cat /etc/firebird/2.5/SYSDBA.password`

> So I autoremoved Firebird and tried to install again.

To remove all configuration files you need use `apt-get purge`:

`sudo apt-get purge firebird2.5-super`